# .Net alternative for OpenCV's camera capture

Tags: .net, camera, video-capture

I am processing video from a camera using OpenCV.Net's camera Capture. Initially I was using more functionality of OpenCV, but because of bugs and performance problems I have rewritten nearly all functionality that I need in C#.

Currently I am still only using OpenCV's Capture to get the video frames from the camera. For this the use of OpenCV seems like overkill.

Is there an alternative in .Net to read frames from a camera?

Comment: Have a look at this thread http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/695276/capture-inmage-from-webcam-by-csharp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am now using AForge, it seems to work well.